# Change items size inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to change specific items size inside the UICollectionViewCell

In my **UIViewController** I declared like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NameCollectionViewCell

    if(retreivedEvents == nil) {
     // print("data not received yet...")
        return cell
    } else {
     // print("new data given")
        cell.anEvent = self.retreivedEvents![indexPath.row]
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        return cell
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NameCollectionViewCell

    let screenHeigh =  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

    cell2.frame.size.height = cellSize * 0.8
    cell2.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height += 50
    cell2.theImageView.frame.size.height = cellSize * 0.8

    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)  
    return CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width,height:cell2.frame.size.height)
}
```

**The issue:**
Every time I run it, the console will show

> Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

. I'm not sure what the error is.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share more informations ? Like where your app crash (line of code) ?

Comment: @JimmyJames Hi, yes. It's inside AppDelegate.swift. 
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: place an exeption breakpoint to debug it

Comment: @JimmyJames It's this line: let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.CellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NameCollectionViewCell

Comment: I think you need check if this cell is nil before doing anything on it. And check the number of item in your collectionview

Comment: That method doesn't return an optional so it can't be nil. Also, I doubt that manifest as an NSArray out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not 100% but I would be very careful about dequeuing a cell for a specific index path inside `sizeForItem`. You're using a cell instance to calculate sizes, but you don't want to use a cell instance that is already in use by the collection view. You'd avoid that by using the dequeue method that doesn't take an `forIndexPath`.